# I want to integrate Vimeo Api in to my android application to show my users the private videos in my Vimeo Account

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, vimeo, vimeo-api

I want to integrate Vimeo Api in to my android application and the problem is after i add the dependency like

```
   implementation "com.github.vimeo.vimeo-networking-java:vimeo-networking:3.12.0"
   implementation "com.github.vimeo.vimeo-networking-java:models:3.12.0"
```

But after syncing with my project when i try to run the project or build it then this error is shown

```
BUILD FAILED in 968ms
21 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 13 up-to-date
 Caused by: 
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: 
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find 
com.github.vimeo.vimeo-networking-java:3.12.0:.
```

note that i have also added the jitpack also

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've put in the dependencies correctly? From the error it seems like you've used

```
implementation "com.github.vimeo.vimeo-networking-java:vimeo-networking:3.12.0"
implementation "com.github.vimeo.vimeo-networking-java:3.12.0"
```

instead of

```
implementation "com.github.vimeo.vimeo-networking-java:vimeo-networking:3.12.0"
implementation "com.github.vimeo.vimeo-networking-java:models:3.12.0"
```

Comment: yes i have done that correctly here is error Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.github.vimeo.vimeo-networking-java:vimeo-networking:3.12.0.

Comment: @Nadeem Check if you're using settings.gradle for dependencyResolutionManagement. If yes then add dependencyResolutionManagement{
    repositories{
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    } 
there.

If the problem still persists please add code for build.gradle project level and settings.gradle in the question.

Comment: Thanks man just before reading your comment done that

Answer (score 0):

We have to add the maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } in dependencyResolutionManagement inside settings.gradle file

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    mavenCentral()
}
 }
```